# How do you debug unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin-studio

I'm running some nunit tests in xamarin studio. They run fine but there does not seem to be an option for running them in debug mode. I've even looked through the keybindings in xamarin to see if it's an option (which is hidden from the menus but can be activated by a custom shortcut)... no luck.

If I want to debug a test, I have to copy and paste the code from the test method into a console application which is hooked up to the same references as my test project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well I've managed to find a way to run all the tests the test project in debug mode: Right-click on the test project -> Run With -> Mono Soft Debugger. However, there's still no way to run an individual test.

Comment: You should be able to right click an individual test in the Unit Tests window and select either Debug Test or Run Test With - Mono Soft Debugger. Does that not work?

Comment: Yeah I finally found the unit testing view along with those options, thanks. I originally thought it was the tests results window where I can rerun the test from. Hence the confusion.